# console.log() not showing in console but in page in Smarty

Tags: google-chrome, smarty, console.log

Ok im having this issue with some smarty files and variables and i need to use console.log.
Issue is console.log is empty and the code appears on the webpage.

for example

console.log('$affiliate.id'); console.log('$affiliate.firstname'); console.log('App started'); console.log("App started");

Shows up in tha page.

PS: Is there some kind of an issue cause its tpl files?
PS2: I tried all the versions like ', " in case i was wrong :P

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you remember to put this code inside `<script>` tags?

Comment: its just not my day, worked like a charm. thanks

PS: Any chance you might know why i get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: affiliate is not defined" error? Is it because its a smarty variable?

Comment: ok I'll post as an answer so you can close it

Comment: Any chance you might know why i get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: affiliate is not defined" error? Is it because its a smarty variable?

Comment: is `$affiliate` a smarty var? Then you should enclose it in `{}` tags, for example `'{$affiliate.id}'`

Comment: Thank you, although it appears it show them as blank but ill sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your code inside `<script>` tags.

For example:

```
<script>
console.log('{$affiliate.id}'); console.log('{$affiliate.firstname}'); console.log('App started'); console.log("App started");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the script tag with a block worked for me:

```
{block name="js_head"}
<script>
console.log('{$affiliate.id}'); console.log('{$affiliate.firstname}'); console.log('App started'); console.log("App started");
</script>
{/block}
```